# RewriteCond with RewriteRule

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am not good with RewriteRule. The following command used to work just find on my previous hosting but it is not working on godaddy.

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)\-(.*)\.html worksub.php?class=$1&p=$2 [QSA]
```

Yesterday @AbsoluteƵERØ helped me resolve the issue for other RewriteRules. The code from that is as follows

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -Multiviews

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

SetEnv HTTP_MOD_REWRITE On
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ([^.]+).html$
RewriteRule ^.* %1.php
</IfModule>
```

I am not sure how to write RewriteCond for the missing Rule mentioned in the first line. And I also want rule for above link through which i can make the url to read as domain.com/class/p/ with class and p being their respective values.

Any help in this regard would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Hope following link helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17058362/restrict-directory-for-friendly-urls-htaccess

Comment: Thank you Lepanto but this example doesn't explain how to do rewrite for links similar to worksub.php?class=$1&p=$2